# Change to php.ini does not have effect

Tags: php, timezone, ini

I added this line to my php.ini file: date.timezone = "Europe/Rome".

But phoinfo() still show me this: date.timezone America/Phoenix America/Phoenix.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Did you restart the web server?

Comment: Its possibly you change the wrong php.ini file, or you don't have yet restart your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also set time zone from your script in case you don't have permission to restart the server:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Phoenix');
//rest of your code. 
?>
```

And [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) the list of supported time zones by PHP.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question. the OP's `phpinfo()` still does not show the change. Please change your answer to really answer the question. This is just a workaround

Answer (score 5):

Did you restart your web server?  `php.ini` is only evaluated when the server starts up.

Comment: The website is on GoDaddy. Probably I can't restart it :(

Answer (score 3):

You have to restart Apache (or whatever server you use).

Answer (score 1):

Is this a discrepancy between command-line execution of PHP versus the regular viewing from a browser?
CLI and web instances can read from different .ini files in some cases.

You'll want to find the 'loaded configuration file' using phpinfo()

From command line in Windows:

```
php.exe -i "phpinfo()" | find ".ini"
```

For Linux I believe:

```
php -i "phpinfo()" | grep ".ini"
```

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy just did this to me too.  The new PHP5 post vars limit broke some of my forms.  So I needed to change the `max_input_vars` setting.  I updated the `php5.ini` file and then had to wait (a few minutes in my case) for the new setting to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `date.timezone = Europe/Rome` in **phpForApache.ini** like you did to **php.ini**.